# Infinite page reloads vue.js method

Tags: vue.js, methods, page-refresh, x-editable, ticket-system

in method When I am updating the ticket status. if we select ticket status = open page is refreshing continuesly.

`isEditableField(fieldname) { if (fieldname === 'status') { return true; } else if (this.ticket.status === 'Closed' || this.ticket.status === 'Resolved') { return false; } else if (this.ticket.status === 'Open'){ location.reload() return true; } },`

Page should be refresh once when we select the ticket status open.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown under which conditions location.reload is called. Since location.reload reloads the page and makes the app to init again, it should be guaranteed this won't happen again. This may be XY problem as this is commonly a hack because a dev didn't find a better way to update the relevant app state.